# add decimal as time

Tags: time, excel-2007, decimal

is there anyway to add a group of decimal numbers and excel treat it as time?
example;
15.00 = 15 hours
1.00 = 1 hour
.20 = 20 minutes
.45 = 45 minutes
.15 = 15 minutes

excel adds this to 16.80, but if you want it as time the answer would be 17.15

17 hours 15 minutes

Comment: Kibbee, you are correct, thats what im attempting to do.
i export data from access and the "time spent" column is decimal. what would be the easiest way to do this? convert the column to time then add?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're working on some sort of time-sheet.  I enter data into an Excel spreadsheet as 0:45, 0:30, 7:00, etc, and make sure the time cells are formatted as [h]:mm, so that times > 24 hours are not displayed as a date.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed your comment now, so I take it that you have the data in Excel as 0.25 = 25 minutes already.

You could add a new column with the following formula:

```
=FLOOR(A1,1) + (A1 - FLOOR(A1,1)) * 5/3
```

(assuming the data is in column A)

You will have strange values if the access data contains numbers like 1.8 (you would get 2 hours 20 minutes in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You my run into a lot of problems, especially if .20 is 20 minutes.  If that is the case, what is .8?  80 minutes? 1 hour 20 minutes?